# Getting UIElements in XCTest using NSPredicate doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nspredicate, xctest

I have a CollectionView with custom cells, that each contain a custom subview, which again each contains a UITextView.

I want to test if these UITextViews contain the correct text (e.g. "The weather in San Francisco is [temperature] degrees").

Therefore, I can access these UITextViews via `app.textViews["The weather in San Francisco is 72 Degrees."]`

However, I would rather include a wildcard or placeholder, for some parts of the text, so I tried to use NSPredicate and only filter for the beginning of the text.

```
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'The weather in San Francisco is'")
   let textView = app.textViews.element(matching: predicate)
   XCTAssert(textView.exists)
```

However, this second approach using NSPredicate always fails, because the textView is not found, while the first one is working. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Try using `value` instead of `label` in your predicate

Comment: thanks, this could resolve the issue!